# Stacking panels in JQuery. The panels have images as their content and should have a small tab of each image visible

Tags: jquery

How can I stack the images to that a tab of of the panels sticks out but does not slide out until the click event occurs?
 I grabbed this code from online but I'm not sure how to modify for what I need done.

**HTML & JQUERY**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmln`enter code here`s="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Panels With jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').css({position:'relative'});
    $(".div1, .div2, .div3").each(function(i,d){
        $(d).css({marginLeft:'-'+$(d).width()+'px',top:'0px',position:'absolute'});

    });
    $('.div1').css({marginLeft:'0px'}).addClass('current');
    $("nav a").click(function() {
        var cls = this.name;
        $('.current').removeClass('current').animate({marginLeft:'-         '+$(this).width()+'px'},1000);
        $('.'+cls).addClass('current')
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.'+cls).animate({marginLeft:0});
        },1000);

    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>
    <a name="div1">SlideToggle Div 1</a>
    <a name="div2">SlideToggle Div 2</a>
    <a name="div3">SlideToggle Div 3</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="container">
    <div class="div1">Content Div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Content Div 2</div>
    <div class="div3">Content Div 3</div>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>

**JQUERY CODE:**

    .div1 {
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    background:url(photo1.png)no-repeat;
    }

    .div2 {
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    background:url(photo3.png)no-repeat;
    }

    .div3 {
     width:800px;
     height:500px;
    background:url(photo2.jpg)no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: How do you start answering this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide the content div's offscreen and animate them in on a mouse-click (while hiding any currently shown div's). I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJMqf/1/) which does that. Below is the modified (and heavily commented) source based on your original post.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmln`enter code here`s="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Panels With jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* "in-document" CSS styles*/
        #div1 {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            background: url(photo1.png) no - repeat;
        }
        #div2 {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            background: url(photo3.png) no - repeat;
        }
        #div3 {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            background: url(photo2.jpg) no - repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //**JQUERY CODE:**
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Set ECMAScript 5 compliance.
            'use strict';
            /* Set the container div's position to a non-static position
             * which allows absolute positioning to work.
            */
            $('#container').css({
                position: 'relative'
            });
            /* Set absolute positioning on all content divs
             * and position them offscreen to the left.
             * You may also want to check out the jQuery UI animations
             * at http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/
            */
            $("#div1, #div2, #div3").each(function (index, elem) {
                $(elem).css({
                    marginLeft: '-' + $(elem).width() + 'px',
                    top: '0px',
                    position: 'absolute'
                });

            });
            //Default the first content div to be shown.
            $('#div1').css({
                marginLeft: '0px'
            }).addClass('current');
            //Add click handlers to the anchor tags
            $("div a").click(function(e) {
                //Grab the hash (href in markup).
                var cls = this.hash.substring(1);
                /*Animate the current content div offscreen to the left
                 *and remove the "current" class from it
                */
                $('.current').animate({
                    marginLeft: '-' + $('.current').width() + 'px'
                }, 1000).removeClass('current');
                //Add the "current" class to the selected content div
                $('#' + cls).addClass('current');
                //Set a callback after 1 second,
                setTimeout(function() {
                    //Callback to slide the content div in from the left.
                    $('#' + cls).animate({
                        marginLeft: 0
                    });
                }, 1000);
                //Prevent any further action in the browser from clicking the anchor.
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav"><!-- <nav> is not a valid HTML 4.01 tag (which is your chosen DOCTYPE), substituted <div> with id of "nav"-->
            <a href="#div1">SlideToggle Div 1</a><!-- changed name to href for easier extraction-->
            <a href="#div2">SlideToggle Div 2</a>
            <a href="#div3">SlideToggle Div 3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="div1">Content Div 1</div><!-- Changed class to id as it makes more sense -->
            <div id="div2">Content Div 2</div>
            <div id="div3">Content Div 3</div>
        </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Should you have further questions, please ask.

If I missed the point of your question, please clarify what you need in your question.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Why `name`, use `id`.

```
<nav>
    <a id="div1" href="#">SlideToggle Div 1</a>
    <a id="div2" href="#">SlideToggle Div 2</a>
    <a id="div3" href="#">SlideToggle Div 3</a>
</nav>
```

No need:

```
$(".div1, .div2, .div3").each(function(i,d){
    $(d).css({marginLeft:'-'+$(d).width()+'px',top:'0px',position:'absolute'});
});
```

Instead of `$(d)`, you can use `$(this)` which refers to the current object being looped.

But then, you can just:

```
$(".div1, .div2, .div3").css({ });
```

I'm not sure about:

```
var cls = this.name;
$('.'+cls).addClass('current'); // Does this work?
```

If you use `id` you can just:

```
$('#id').addClass('current');
```

Comment: Pete, This seems to be the best answer to my question! Thank-you to everyone for your answers! Sorry for the late response. I've been working on this for a while.